# sum numbers of XML-nodes if they are on the same page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have an XML-file with products and their prices. The numbers of products in the XML-file are variable, but will be at least 10. As an example of the XML I made a very simple one below:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Productname>Product 1</Productname>
        <Price>90.45</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Productname>Product 2</Productname>
        <Price>30,25</Price>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I have an XSLT which makes an invoice of all of the products in XML in PDF. No problem so far.
Here's my problem: I would like to have a sum of the products on each page. So if Product 1 to 5 are on page 1 I would like to have a sum of the prices of those products. If Product 6 to 10 are on page 2 then I would like to have a sum of the products 1 to 10. If product 7 to 15 are on page 3 then I would like to have a sum of the products 1 to 15 and so on.

The products and prices are in a table which adds a row for each product. The problem is that I can't find a way how to find out which products are on one page.

Comment: This looks like something that could be solved by using `fo:marker` and `fo:retrieve-marker`. Here is an example: http://markmail.org/message/t6hl5mo6eo5mppj4.

Comment: @mzjn: That looks like it's worth an Answer. Then this question won't have to stay on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly how to write your stylesheet, but this looks like a problem that can be solved by using `fo:marker` and `fo:retrieve-marker` (or perhaps `fo:retrieve-table-marker`).

A marker is a named piece of text or calculated value from the source document that is "retrieved" for display in static content areas or table headers/footers in the output. Markers are often used for running page headers, but they can also be used to display subtotals of an accumulating quantity. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker.

Here is a complete example: http://markmail.org/message/t6hl5mo6eo5mppj4. Hopefully you can adapt it to your needs.